# File served from browser cache takes 500ms to "download"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, browser-cache

In Chrome, with dev tools open, I take a look at a large file (around 1MB) served from browser cache.
Although served from cache, the file takes around 500ms to "download"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes reading a file from cache is slow.

You can take a more detailed look at this in `about:net-internals`